# Unable to gather error info from halting Powershell script

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I'm writing a script that will watch a directory for any new mp4 files, then convert the file using HandBrake's CLI tool.  The logic that watches the directory for changes works by itself, but if I drop a large video into the "watched" directory the conversion fails since it kicks off as soon as it sees a new file, before the file has time to finish copying.

I'm using a do until loop to check if the file is locked/downloading and then continues once the file is unlocked/writable.  The loop works as a stand-alone script, but when used inside the filesystem watcher the script it will halt without any errors on this line:

`[System.IO.FileStream] $fs = $convertingFile.OpenWrite();`

This occurs regardless if $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue" is commented out.  I've been unable to gather any log output to see why the script is halting using Start-Transcript or Out-File.

**How should I best gather error info about why the script halts once it hits this line?**

Bonus:  *Why might this script not provide error information?*

```
    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

    function Start-FileSystemWatcher {

      [CmdletBinding()]
      param(
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Path,
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateSet('Changed','Created','Deleted','Renamed')]
        [string[]]$EventName,
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Filter,
        [Parameter()]
        [System.IO.NotifyFilters]$NotifyFilter,
        [Parameter()]
        [switch]$Recurse,
        [Parameter()]
        [scriptblock]$Action
      )

      #region Build  FileSystemWatcher

      $FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
      if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Path')) {
        $Path = $PWD
      }
      $FileSystemWatcher.Path = $Path
      if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Filter')) {
        $FileSystemWatcher.Filter = $Filter
      }

      if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('NotifyFilter')) {
        $FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter = $NotifyFilter
      }

      if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Recurse')) {
        $FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $True
      }

      if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('EventName')) {
        $EventName = 'Changed','Created','Deleted','Renamed'
      }

      if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Action')) {
        $Action = {
          switch ($Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType) {
            'Renamed' {
              $Object = "{0} was  {1} to {2} at {3}" -f $Event.SourceArgs[-1].OldFullPath,
              $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType,
              $Event.SourceArgs[-1].FullPath,
              $Event.TimeGenerated
            }

            Default {
              $Object = "{0} was  {1} at {2}" -f $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath,
              $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType,
              $Event.TimeGenerated
            }
          }

          $WriteHostParams = @{
            ForegroundColor = 'Green'
            BackgroundColor = 'Black'
            Object = $Object
          }

          Write-Host @WriteHostParams
        }

      }

      $ObjectEventParams = @{
        InputObject = $FileSystemWatcher
        Action = $Action

      }

      foreach ($Item in $EventName) {
        $ObjectEventParams.EventName = $Item
        $ObjectEventParams.SourceIdentifier = "File.$($Item)"
        Write-Verbose "Starting watcher for Event: $($Item)"
        $Null = Register-ObjectEvent @ObjectEventParams
      }

    }

    $FileSystemWatcherParams = @{
      Path = 'X:\share\scripts\ps\converter\input'
      Recurse = $True
      NotifyFilter = 'FileName'
      Verbose = $True
      Action = {
        $Item = Get-Item $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
        $WriteHostParams = @{
          ForegroundColor = 'Green'
          BackgroundColor = 'Black'
        }

        $inputFile = "${PWD}\input\$($Item.Name)".trim()
        $outputFile = "${PWD}\output\$($Item.Name)".trim()
        $logFile = "${PWD}\log\$($Item.Name).txt"
        $testLogFile = "${PWD}\log\$($Item.Name)(t).txt"

        function mp4-Func {
          Start-Transcript -path $logFile
          Write-Host "New mp4 file detected..."
          $convertingFile = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileInfo -ArgumentList $inputFile
          $locked = 1
          do {
            [System.IO.FileStream] $fs = $convertingFile.OpenWrite();
            if (!$?) {
                Write-Host "Can't convert yet, file appears to be loading..."
                sleep 2
            }
            else {
                $fs.Dispose()
                $locked = 0
            }
          } until ($locked -eq 0)

          Write-Host "File unlocked and ready for conversion."
          HandBrake
          Stop-Transcript
          $WriteHostParams.Object = "Finished converting: $($Item.Name)"
        }

        function HandBrake {
          .\HandBrakeCLI.exe --input "$inputFile" `
                             --output "$outputFile" `
                             --format av_mp4 `
                             --encoder x264 `
                             --vb 1700 `
                             --two-pass `
                             --aencoder copy:aac `
                             --ab 320 `
                             --arate 48 `
                             --mixdown stereo
        }

        switch -regex ($Item.Extension) {
          '\.mp4' { mp4-Func }
        }

        Write-Host @WriteHostParams
      }

    }
    @( 'Created') | ForEach-Object {
      $FileSystemWatcherParams.EventName = $_
      Start-FileSystemWatcher @FileSystemWatcherParams
    }
```

Comment: Your post isn't really a clear question, but has several sort of implied. I've taken a stab at an answer, but please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I've tried to rewrite the problem description and have provided a couple questions that should be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that  `$ErrorActionPreference` only impact errors at the level of cmdlets, while you hitting a problem in non-cmdlet code.    For that, you'll probably need a `try`/`catch` construct.

Comment: I upvoted your answer but unfortunately, my reputation precedes me.  I'll employ the try/catch to pull the exception message out and will let you know the results!

Comment: I converted the "do while" loop to use try/catch rather than the if statement and used $_.Exception.Message and $_.Exception.ItemName to see what was going on.  The exception is what I would see normally when running the script standalone, but the $ErrorActionPreference would roll by it normally.  The if statement was the wrong approach... from this point forward I'll use try/catch/finally to better effect!  Thank you for your help.  =)   I'll post a new answer with these details & code, but will still recommend your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Burt_Harris' answer (please upvote his answer over this one), I changed the "do while" loop so that it would use try/catch rather than an if/else statement.  By using $*.Exception.Message and $*.Exception.ItemName I was able to better understand why the script was halting at that particular line.

Working code:

```
Do {
    Try {
      [System.IO.FileStream] $fs = $convertingFile.OpenWrite()
      $fs.Dispose()
      $locked = 0
    }
    Catch {
      $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
      $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
      Write-Host $ErrorMessage
      Write-Host $FailedItem
      Write-Host "Can't convert yet, file appears to be loading..."
      sleep 5
      continue
    }
  } until ($locked -eq 0)
```